# Angular 7 HttpClient post 404

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-httpclient

I can't seem to get anything other than a GET request to work in my Angular 7 app. Here is the code:

```
prefix: string = 'assets/data/';

getJsonFile = (fileLocation: string) => {
    return this.http.get(`${this.prefix}${fileLocation}.json`);
};

postJsonFile = (fileLocation: string, data: any) => {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.put(`${this.prefix}${fileLocation}.json`, data, options);
};
```

fileLocation is passed in and I am passing the same string, 'selling'.
The GET returns successfully and the PUT throws a 404 (Not Found) error in the console:

```
PUT http://localhost:4200/assets/data/selling.json 404 (Not Found) scheduleTask @ zone.js:3243
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/selling.json", ok: false, …}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you expect from a PUT to a static file?

Comment: PUT or POST doesn't work. What do I need to do to append another JSON object to this file?

Comment: You need to not be using a file, you'll need an actual backend.

Comment: Okay, thanks @jonrsharpe I was just trying to make it quick and simple using a JSON file but I guess that makes sense.

Comment: If you don't need permanent storage, you could use https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: Don't use your Google Search terms as a title for questions on Stack Overflow.  Ask an actual question in your title instead.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I'll check it out.